# Apple Programming Guides on Kindle?

Tags: mac, pdf, kindle

Does anyone else here really wish they could send apple programming guides to their kindle? The apple programming guides are great learning tools but they are online, and multi-page and I am not sure of the best way to get them on my kindle (for reading on the bus, or whatever). Has anyone here found a way, or can suggest a way, to send an entire programming guide to PDF?

Comment: Don't the online programming guides you want have an icon in the top right corner for getting a pdf version?

Comment: uh... where the heck did that button come from?? I swear I am not new to this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the PDF version here
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iPhoneAppProgrammingGuide.pdf

Or by clicking on the PDF button on the upper right of ANY Apple programming guide.

Then drop it on to your Kindle :)

You can also email it to your Kindle using whatever email address is indicated in your settings.

If you need to convert the original PDF for Kindle there are few online programs that will do that.

Or put the word 'convert' in the subject line of your email when you email the pdf to your kindle.